# Database for commercially available restriction enzymes?

Tags: database, restriction-enzymes

I need a database that contains a complete list of commercial restriction enzymes: name of the enzyme & recognition site.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably talking about type II endonucleases, there are a few databases available from the companies which sell these enzymes like NEB or Thermo Fisher. Additionally tools like NEBcutter, where you can paste a sequence and get all recognition sites for restriction endonucleases in this sequence are useful.
I linked them below in the references.

Edit: Thanks to @Michael_A I have added the lonk to the Rebase Database. It is a database which tries to be a complete ressource on restriction enzymes.

References:

1. [NEB Enzyme Finder](https://enzymefinder.neb.com/#!#nebheader)
2. [Anza Restriction Enzyme Finder Tool](https://www.thermofisher.com/de/de/home/life-science/cloning/restriction-enzyme-digestion-and-ligation/restriction-enzyme-cloning/anza-enzyme-selection-tool.html)
3. [NEBCutter](https://nc3.neb.com/NEBcutter/)
4. [Rebase](http://rebase.neb.com/rebase/rebase.html)

Comment: I think you should add [rebase](http://rebase.neb.com/rebase/rebase.html) to this list, it is is an overt attempt at a 'complete' and includes information about commercial availability.

Comment: @Michael_A Thanks for the tip, I added the info.